# Using an Embedding layer in the Keras functional API

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Doing basic things with the Keras Functional API seems to produce errors. For example, the following fails:

```
from keras.layers import InputLayer, Embedding
input = InputLayer(name="input", input_shape=(1, ))
embedding = Embedding(10000, 64)(input)
```

This produces the error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'

I can then "cheat" by using the `input_length` argument but this then fails when I try to concatenate two such embeddings:

```
from keras.layers import InputLayer, Embedding, Concatenate
embedding1 = Embedding(10000, 64, input_length=1)
embedding2 = Embedding(10000, 64, input_length=1)
concat = Concatenate()([embedding1 , embedding2])
```

This gives the error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Same error when I use "concatenate" (lower case) instead (some sources seem to say that this should be used instead if using the functional API).

What am I doing wrong?

I am on tensorflow version `2.3.1`, keras version `2.4.3`, python version `3.6.7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest to use `tf.keras` and not `keras`.

It doesn't work because `InputLayer` is an instance of `keras.Layer`, whereas `keras.layers.Input` is an instance of `Tensor`. The argument to `layer.__call__()` should be `Tensor` and not `keras.Layer`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((1,))
print(type(inputs)) # <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(1,))
print(type(input_layer)) # <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer'>
```

You use `InputLayer` with `Sequential` API. When you use functional API you should use `tf.keras.layers.Input()` instead:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((1, ), name="input", )
embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 64)(inputs)
```

Same with the second example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((1, ), name="input", )
embedding1 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 64)(inputs)
embedding2 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 64)(inputs)

concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([embedding1, embedding2])
```